# Paste string together based on author

Tags: r, string

I want to merge/paste (`paste(c(...), collapse=" ")`) strings in a dataframe based on value (`author`) in a different column. I am looking for an efficient way to do it.

```
df <- data.frame(author = c("Shakespeare", 
                            "Dante",
                            "Proust",
                            "Shakespeare", 
                            "Dante",
                            "Proust",
                            "Shakespeare"),
                 text = c("Put the wild waters in this roar, allay them",
                          "Ma tu perche' ritorni a tanta noia?",
                          "Longtemps, je me suis couché de bonne heure",
                          "The very virtue of compassion in thee",
                          "Pensa oramai qual fu colui che degno",
                          "Quelle horreur! me disais-je",
                          "She said thou wast my daughter; and thy father"))
```

And the end result should be

```
result <- c("Put the wild waters in this roar, allay them The very virtue of compassion in thee She said thou wast my daughter; and thy father",
            "Ma tu perche' ritorni a tanta noia? Pensa oramai qual fu colui che degno",
            "Longtemps, je me suis couché de bonne heure Quelle horreur! me disais-je")
names(result) <- c("Shakespeare","Dante","Proust")
result
# Shakespeare 
# "Put the wild waters in this roar, allay them The very virtue of compassion in thee She said thou wast my daughter; and thy father" 
# Dante 
# "Ma tu perche' ritorni a tanta noia? Pensa oramai qual fu colui che degno" 
# Proust 
# "Longtemps, je me suis couché de bonne heure Quelle horreur! me disais-je"
```

I guess I should somehow use some function from the `apply` family. Something like

```
apply( df[??? , 2 , paste , collapse = " " )
```

but I am not sure how to pass the condition and then obtain as result the name of the author to which the pasted strings correspond...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tapply` works more or less exactly as you expected:

```
tapply(df$text, df$author, paste, collapse = " ")
```

A more *en vogue* solution would be to use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(author) %>% summarize(passage = paste(text, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: `array <- tapply(df$text, df$author, paste, collapse = " ")
result <- as.character(array)
names(result) <- names(array)`

Comment: `aggregate(text~author, df, paste, collapse=" ")` as well